# Like button action not showing on user's walls

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm using the iFrame Like button on a page. When I click it, it goes to my wall saying I liked a link. This is good. However, when other people try it, it doesn't show up on their wall. Does the timeline layout affect this? I'm not using that layout, but my testers that aren't able to get the like to show on their wall are.

I've found similar problems on here, but nothing that's helped. I have OG meta tags included on the page that aren't being read correctly either.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some hints:

Have you checked the permissions for the FB-application? 
Does it only work with users that are registered as developers/testers for the FB-application?