# Facebook 'Like' not incrementing

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

What do I need to do to get a FB like counter working for a website - not a FB page/app/anything else.

I've followed the dev guide here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

I've read the following questions & comments [Facebook Like Button doesn't increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159174/facebook-like-button-doesnt-increment) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211964/cannot-make-standard-facebook-like-button-code-work [Like button action not showing on user's walls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685331/like-button-action-not-showing-on-users-walls) and others.

I've put this at the top of the page so it's just after the body tag when it's rendered

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I've put this where I want the like counter to go (website name changed to avoid unnecessary accusations):

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://mywebsite.com" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

Result:

Button appears as expected.
When clicking like a (appears to be) JS window appears asking to add a comment - cancel and comment buttons are disabled.
When I enter text, buttons are enabled.
Click comment
Like increments from 0 to 1
refresh page - counter resets to 0
Subsequent clicks flash up the JS dialog and it disappears and counter stays at 0 (can just about see that it flashes up 'You like this' with further comment box but disappears before I can do anything)
No message on FB user's wall to indicate any like or anything about the website

Do I need to create a FB app?  I see some references to appId but not on the FB 'like' developer page.

Frustrated!

A dummy's guide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an FB app at https://developers.facebook.com/ for the like button to work. Once you have created your app, make sure that you select your app in the Get Code window when creating your [like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button).

Comment: Thank you for the tip but I just don't get it - I'm half way through registering/creating a new app and it's asking me for a minimum of 4 screenshots of how I will use FB in the website.  How can I do that if I can't register in order to use FB within my website???
I've read this https://en-gb.facebook.com/help/110919988996182 but each branch of the "Create FB App Getting Started Guide" (whether the Canvas app or external website - they start at integrating the SDK and how to integrate login/like etc. .... they skip the part about creating an app and exactly what they want with the screenshots

Comment: Marking answer as accepted because it certainly feels correct it's just that I'm having further issues of understanding what is required to make the app public.

Comment: I give up - I generated new code with the appId but the counter still stays at 0 when the page is refreshed.
What am I doing wrong? The website is jobcloud.cz